# Optional packages in LFS ( do I need to install a package again after I install an optional package later? )

Tags: lfs

I am building BLFS 8.4

If I install an optional package later, then do I need to install all the previous packages again so that they can take the benefit of the optional package?

Comment: This sounds almost like a certainty.

Comment: Not necessarily *all* previous packages... just the ones that list it as ***Optional*** and you want/need to utilize it. The exception to this would be those listed as ***Optional Runtime Dependencies***.

Comment: What about optional packages that are optional to other packages? This would create a hierarchy!

Comment: These days I install most optional packages... there are a few that I won't (Doxygen...). If I later find out that I want a package that was optional to something I already installed, I don't sweat it. To fulfill dependencies (optional or otherwise), I work backwards. For example, if I want to install Firefox, then I first have to install Autoconf2.13, next I have to install Cbindgen, but for that I first have to install rustc, and so on.... It helps to go through and write all of them down in the order you will install them before you start.